# Deploy customized Bot Framework web chat to Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I've customized my web chat by cloning from the source [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). No I want to deploy this to Azure and host it on one of my websites. I'm building the app based on the instructions in the above. When I try deploying, I either get a "You do not have permission to view this page" or a 503 Gateway Error.

Where should I point the Azure website to look at. When I run locally, I need to point it to one of the samples in the samples directory. When I try doing the same on Azure, the chat never loads and shows a blank window. Is there a mistake in the way the app is being deployed ?

Comment: Hi Vijay! Can you post the code you're using to display the bot on your page and/or the steps you're taking to deploy it?

Comment: `When I try doing the same on Azure, the chat never loads and shows a blank window.` You can check if *botchat.css* and *botchat.js* are loaded as expected via  F12 developer tools Network tab, and you can check if any error appear in developer tools Console tab.

Answer (score 0):

> "You do not have permission to view this page"

I suspect that there is no default page in your Azure website, which cause the issue. You can add/specify a web page as [the default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#default-documents).

***Same issue appears if no default document (web page) in my project  folder:***

[image]

> I've customized my web chat by cloning from the source here. Now I want to deploy this to Azure and host it on one of my websites.

You can follow the following steps to customize&build your own Web Chat, and then add it to your website.

1) Refer to the steps described in [“Building Web Chat”](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#building-web-chat) to build your own Web Chat

2) Include your own customized `botchat.css` and `botchat.js` in your website project

3) Add references to `botchat.css` and `botchat.js` in the  section of the web page

4) Add and initiate BotChat with `directLine_secret`, `botid` etc information

```
<script>
    BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: "{directline_secret}" },
        user: { id: 'You' },
        bot: { id: '{bot_id}' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));
</script>
```

5) Test it on local, if WebChat works as expected then publish the website to Azure

I did a test with the above steps and it works fine both on local and Azure website.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vijay, any updates? Do you resolve the problem now?